# Alternatives to Excel forms for data collection?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Currently I am receiving bunch of excel forms from many people each month and I need to consolidate them into one single report

Problems:

1. Even though I have given people a template to follow, the format is always changed by the users (adding extra columns, rows, unnecessary comments, etc.), making consolidation impossible before cleaning up the files to the standard format
2. Data is not consistent as some of them have different names for the same thing or abbreviations are often used. The built in data validation function is not good enough because copy and paste would override the validation.

I guess I am looking for a web solution to these problems because I want to eliminate the process of sending update files every time I have made tiny changes. And also I want to make it interactive (double click to drill in, charts, etc.). Please advice where to start, I know some html and JavaScript, and I am happy to pick up new programming language if it is needed, thanks.

Comment: For your last point, you might want to try Google Drive.

Comment: The variety of ways to answer this are dependent on knowing more about the data you want to collect. On one end of the spectrum would be data that would match up nicely with Adobe Acrobat's form collection process, and on the other end might be a totally custom and highly dynamic web based system. How flexible does your system need to be? You mentioned users making changes, should they be able to?

Comment: You may want to look at [Smartsheet](http://www.smartsheet.com/)

Comment: No ideally the template should only be modified by me. Sometimes they put comments in cells where only numeric value is supposed to be there, which make the whole consolidation process difficult(errors happen during calculations, etc.). So I think I would need something that allows me to write a script to check stuff like isNumeric() to ensure what they entered is valid. Blocking the copy&paste function is not an ideal solution because some of these people actually got reports from another system, so they'd just paste in the data while some other reports are entered manually entirely.

Comment: How many total pieces of information are they providing? How many of those are potentially being copied from contiguous cells when pasted into your form? If the data leans heavily toward Excel it is possible to distribute a heavily locked down spreadsheet that they can fill in, if not then a range of other options is there.

Comment: Do you mean by using macro? What are some of the other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build this as a List in SharePoint.  You can start by Importing the structure and data from your existing Excel table.  You can do simple validation and add /rename columns, set up multiple views, form design - all through the SharePoint UI without any code. SharePoint Forms are extendable by code if you really need to.

Users accessing the List using a Web Browser can choose the Datasheet view - the List then behaves like a simple Spreadsheet with filtering, sorting etc on columns, and you can copy and paste ranges of cells to and from Excel.

SharePoint lists can be integrated e.g. with Reporting Services for reporting or with Integration Services for integration with other data sources or destinations.

Comment: sounds good, but looks like my company has restricted the right to create forms...anyway

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Microsoft Infopath for data collection.  This is what this program is designed to do.  The data can be collected in MSSQL, Access or saved in an XML format for later retrieval.  The most common use is with Microsoft SharePoint.

Comment: Note that Microsoft have discontinued Infopath (unfortunately IMO).  http://blogs.office.com/2014/01/31/update-on-infopath-and-sharepoint-forms/